# Redirect to detail page after saving record using force:navigateToSobject

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I am getting error as

> "This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
>   $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined]
>   Callback failed:
>   apex://QuickCreateOppCtr/ACTION$creatOpportunityRecord Failing
>   descriptor: {c:QuickCreateOpp}" after saving record.

Record is created but not redirecting opportunity detail page from Account list view but it is redirecting from account detail page

Below is the lightning component controller.

```
action.setCallback(this,function(result){
            component.set("v.isShow",false);
            //component.set("v.objDetail.AccountId", component.get("v.recordId"));
            //alert('component.get("v.recordId") ---->' +component.get("v.recordId"));
            var oppId = result.getReturnValue();
            alert('Opportunity is created. oppId -->'+oppId); 

            var navEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
         navEvent.setParams({
              recordId: result.getReturnValue(),
              slideDevName: "detail"
         });
         navEvent.fire();

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

Comment: According to documentation, this event is handled by the one.app container. It’s supported in Lightning Experience, the Salesforce app, and Lightning communities. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToSObject/documentation). It will not work in VF page as(or) lightning out

Comment: pranay, it's not duplicate.

Comment: I am using this component to create opportunity record from Account detail page and Account list view page. If I create from Account detail, it's redirecting opp detail page. but when i am creating record from Account list view, it's throwing error.

Comment: Can you give us the background about your scenario?

Comment: I have created lightning component to create opportunity for account detail page and account list view. I am able to create record from Account detail and redirect to opp detail. and i can create record from account list view but unable to redirect to detail page.

Comment: I do believe that this is a duplicate, and am voting accordingly. Your exact situation may be different, but the solution is likely to be the same. If you still don't think that your question is a duplicate, it's up to you to _explain why_ it isn't a duplicate.